# MongoDB Catalina: connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: database, mongodb, macos, macos-catalina

I just updated my mac to **Catalina 10.15.2** and I can't running MongoDB.

When I send the command `mongo` I receive this message

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
```

and the only way to make Mongo work is to restart the Mac.

If I check the process with the command `ps` I don't see the process already on and the port **27017** is available.

I already tried to run the follow command:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew reinstall mongodb-community
brew services restart mongodb-community
```

and if I run the follow command:

```
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep mongod
```

no results.

I tried to run `mongod` before `mongo` as well and the result is:

```
2019-12-18T12:17:45.916+0100 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-12-18T12:17:45.920+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=9375 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Marcos-MacBook-Pro.local
2019-12-18T12:17:45.920+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.1
2019-12-18T12:17:45.920+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: edf6d45851c0b9ee15548f0f847df141764a317e
2019-12-18T12:17:45.920+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2019-12-18T12:17:45.920+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-12-18T12:17:45.920+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-12-18T12:17:45.920+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-12-18T12:17:45.920+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-12-18T12:17:45.920+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-12-18T12:17:45.920+0100 E  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Permission denied
2019-12-18T12:17:45.920+0100 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 40486 at src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp 693
2019-12-18T12:17:45.920+0100 F  -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Someone can help me please? I appreciate it

Comment: `sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`, then restart mongod.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative way to fix this Catalina Mac OS root & mongodb connection issue, do the following:

Install Homebrew, if you have it, reinstall it again

run the following commands in the terminal

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

brew untap mongodb/brew && brew tap mongodb/brew

brew install mongodb-community@4.2
```

The issue is mongo cannot find `/db/data` because there is no directory, so you have to create one:

`cd ~` (this should take you to your `Users` folder)

from the `Users` folder make your own db/data folder by running the follow commands:

`mkdir db` & cd inside `db folder`

inside the `db folder` run: `mkdir data` & cd inside `data folder`

run this command: `mongod --dbpath ~/data/db`
(inside the `Users/data/db/` folder you just created)

Now open a new terminal tab &
run: `cd ~` (brings you back to Users) -> now run : `cd .. & cd .. again (do this twice)`
(now you should be in the folder ***before Users***)

(now find `tmp folder`) cd into the `/tmp folder`

**delete the sock file (this is giving you connection issues)**

delete it by running: `rm -rf mongodb-27017.sock`

now run command: `mongo` (this should work now)

inside mongo shell run command: `db.verion()`
if you see a version, your connection works.

**From now on to run mongodb database & connection you will have to have two separate tabs open at all times whenever you want to work on your projects**

```
Example:

in one terminal tab run command -> mongod --dbpath ~/data/db 
(this starts the connection)

in the other terminal tab run command: mongo
(this starts the shell)
```

These both have to be running..

```
Side Note:
you no longer need to start
the connection by running 
brew services start mongo-community anymore.
```

remember `mongod --dbpath ~/data/db` is basically -> `mongod` command now.. The Mac OS Catalina Update created root permission problems, that is why `mongod` command alone never worked before.

Hope this helped you. Goodluck.

Answer (score 2):

Faced a similar issue with macOS Big Sur. After trying all the approaches mentioned above including

- updating homebrew
- reinstalling MongoDB, MongoDB community and setting up a `/System/Volumes/Data/data/dbfolder`

This command worked for me `mongod --dbpath=/System/Volumes/Data/data/db`

reference: https://medium.com/codespace69/mongodb-troubleshooting-errors-for-beginners-and-macos-catalina-31befd99f6c8

Answer (score 1):

```
This error is caused due to ownership issues.
Here we are changing the ownership to 'mongodb' user.
```

```
Command 1: deletes the /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock file
$sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

```
Command 2: starts mongod service
$sudo service mongod start
```

```
Command 3: shows the file with its ownership details
ls -lsah /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

```
output
0 srwx------ 1 mongodb mongodb 0 Aug 24 04:01 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue after upgrading to Catalina. Tried lots of ways to solve the issue, what eventually helped was reinstalling brew, and then following steps listed on official mongodb site.

So:

1. Uninstall brew:
   `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)`
2. Install it again:
   `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`
3. Follow steps to install and run monbo service:
   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/